# Python True/False in string

Tags: python

How to make a function what will be wirtting true when username is also in pass .. No depends if some is bigg letter or lower letter

[image: How to make a function what will be wirtting true when username is also in pass .. No depends if some is bigg letter or lower letter]

Comment: Hello, can you show your attempts so far and avoid including code as image (include it directly as text) ?

Comment: If username is in password i mean PETER must be in pass

Comment: `if password.lower() in username`

Comment: `if password.lower() in username.lower()` **

Comment: jupyter-notebook has nothing to do with this question

Comment: Please don't attach images of code. Add you code as codeblock

Comment: Tomáš: What do you ask for ? Username in password **or** password in username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username = "peter123"
password = "peTeR"

def check(username, password):
    username = username.lower()
    password = password.lower()
    return password in username

print(check(username, password))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to solve this problem, this are listed below:

1. In Operator
   We can you "in" operator here. "in" operator with strings returns true, if substring is in main string else false. 
   For example:
   a. "abc" in "xabcd"
   => True

b. "abc" in "xabdcd"
=> False

```
def userpass(username, password):
    return password.lower() in username.lower() 

userpass("pEter32", "PETER")
```

2. Find Method:
   Find method returns a index, if substring is present in string else it returns -1

   ```
   def userpass(username, password): 
       index = username.lower().find(password.lower()) 
       if index>=0: 
           return True 
       else: 
           return False
   userpass("pEter32", "PETER")
   ```
3. Index Method
   This is same as find method, but raises an exception if str not found.

   ```
   def userpass(username, password): 
       try: 
           index = username.lower().index(password.lower())  
           return True 
       except: 
           return False 
   userpass("pEter32", "PETER")
   ```

Comment: Sure, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
lambda name, password: password.lower() in name.lower()
```

In python3's repl:

```py
>>> pairs = (('peter123', 'PeTeR'),
...          ('123Peter', 'PETER'),
...          ('123pEtEr123', 'non-peter'))

>>> [(lambda nam, pwd: pwd.lower() in nam.lower())(n, p) for n, p in pairs]
[True, True, False]
```

(Or simply

```py
>>> [password.lower() in name.lower() for name, password in pairs]
[True, True, False]
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
import re
def nameInPassword(userName, password):
    flag = re.search(userName, password, re.IGNORECASE)
    if flag == None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(nameInPassword('Peter', '123')
```